# Utilize Photoshop Image Processor Script outside photoshop

Tags: photoshop, background-process

is there a way to utilize Photoshop's Image Processor Script outside photoshop. Preferrably as a background process that way if I can keep working in Photoshop while I am processing tons of images.

Sorry if this is not the right place to post this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone have an answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

Photoshop can't do that. You can use command line software(no GUI) like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).
Here's an example in bash which shows how to resize all the .tga in folder to 64x96 px and convert to .png format:

```
for tga in *.tga; do convert $tga'[64x96]' ${tga/\.tga/.png};done
```

Advantages ?

1. Runs in background (command line)
2. Free
3. Opensource
4. Multi platform (linux,windows,osx,ios)
5. Well [documented](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, Photoshop has to be open to use it's image processor. This is why if you wanted to add 50 to each pixels blue value (making the picture more blue) you would not want to do this in photoshop. You would want to loop through the array of pixels in Java or some other language.

In photoshop you would have to write the script to make a selection of one pixel, then edit it's color, deselect that pixel, make a new selection to the pixel next to it and then start the loop over again. It would be very process intensive and utilized the GUI the whole while.

Answer (score 0):

You can do bulk actions with the help of Adobe Bridge.

For that you need to **create an Action in Photoshop** after that you can do that action on bulk images with the help of Adobe Bridge for example Doing watermark or applying filters.

friendly reminder is you cannot use your computer till action completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on Photoshop, you can use "Photoshop server". You would have another machine with running Photoshop. And you would use Photoshop Connect SDK http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/sdk.html on local network.

Then you can execute script via TCP protocol. And as you said... Image processor is script. When script is done, Photoshop returns value back. So you can make request for image paths or anything else if you want.